# Substituting a model property with "type":"string" and "format":"time" in Springfox

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi, springfox

## Intro

In a plain and naked spring-boot project I have one model class with a single property of Type `java.time.LocalTime`.
If I run the project, springfox detects the `LocalTime` as a non-builtin class and puts it under `definitions`.

```
{
  "ExampleDto": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "time": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/LocalTime"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Not what I want.

---

## What I actually want

... is to have a property of type string with a custom format named "time" like this:

```
{
  "ExampleDto": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "time": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "time"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

## What I could come up with

If I add an `AlternateTypeRule` from `LocalTime` to `String`, I only get half of what I want.

```
{
  "ExampleDto": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "time": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course I also experimented with a lot of things but I never managed to set the "format" of the property.
I found out that somehow calling the constructor `io.swagger.models.properties.StringProperty#StringProperty(java.lang.String)` with "time" as argument would do the trick but I could not find out how to achieve that.

I set up a project on github to showcase my problem.
https://github.com/LorenzSchumann/springfoxshowcase

Answer (score 0):

Just found a close suggestion in [Springfox documentation](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/):

> Q. How do we use Java 8 types easily. LocalDateTime?
>
> The easiest way to to configure dates is via `Docket#directModelSubstitute(LocalDateTime.class, String.class)`. If these are ISO 8601 dates that conform to a string format i.e. yyyy-MM-dd’T’HH:mm’Z'. However you won’t have any format or validation info.
>
> **The way to correctly map the "Date" and "DateTime" types** to their corresponding swagger types:
>
> - Substitute "Date" types (java.util.LocalDate, org.joda.time.LocalDate) by java.sql.Date.
> - Substitute "DateTime" types (java.util.ZonedDateTime, org.joda.time.LocalDateTime, …​) by java.util.Date.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> docket
>   .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, java.sql.Date.class)
>   .directModelSubstitute(LocalDateTime.class, java.util.Date.class)
> ```

In your case it would be:

```
docket.directModelSubstitute(LocalTime.class, java.util.Date.class)
```

After which the output will be:

```
...
"properties": {
  "time": {
    "type": "string",
    "format": "date-time"
  }
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Aivaras. I made use of your suggestion and found that the definition does not match the actual result. When the spec says date-time (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6) it has to have a date part which the actual result does not have.

Comment: This is why I've said it's a _close_ suggestion :) It does not answer the question in full and I am not even sure if it is possible to generate schema with either "time" or just "date" formats, the other available ones in schema https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#dates-and-times